# can't find contract after compile successfully in remix: No Contract Compiled Yet

Tags: solidity, abi, bytecode, compiler

I compile this file in 0.4.8 successfully,

```
pragma solidity 0.4.8;
contract A {
    function f(uint[] arr) constant external returns (uint len) {
        assembly {
            pop arr := len 
        }
    }
}

contract B{
    function codeAt(address _addr) internal returns (bytes o_code) {
        assembly {
             // retrieve the size of the code, this needs assembly
            let size := extcodesize(_addr)
            // allocate output byte array - this could also be done without assembly
            // by using o_code = new bytes(size)
            o_code := mload(0x40)
            // new "memory end" including padding
            mstore(0x40, add(o_code, and(add(add(size, 0x20), 0x1f), not(0x1f))))
            // store length in memory
            mstore(o_code, size)
            // actually retrieve the code, this needs assembly
            extcodecopy(_addr, add(o_code, 0x20), 0, size)
        }
    }
}

contract C{
    uint256 public x = 1;
}
```

but I can not find it, it shows:

> No Contract Compiled Yet

[image]
Even I can not find the bytecode and ABI, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I compiled each contract separately.

Contract B [image]

Contract B successfully compiled

Contract C
[image: Contract C]

Contract C successfully compiled

Contract A
[image]

Contract A throws an error `stack too deep`

It's giving you this error because the function is trying to store too many local variables to the stack. the stack can easily overflow.

You can try to remove some of the local variables from the function.

Comment: Hope this helped. Keep me updated1